# Webservice using jaxrs, starting a timer

Tags: java, timer, jax-ws

I am trying to start a timer, but get a  "Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization."
I am using Jax-rs on tomcat.

```
@Path("/startGame")
public void startGame(){
    GameTimer timer = new GameTimer(1000);
    timer.start();
}
```

This is the GameTimer:

```
 public class GameTimer {

private Timer timer;
private long interval;

public GameTimer(long interval) {
    this.interval = interval;
}

/**
 * 
 */
public void start() {
    this.timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            new GameEvent(GameEvent.STEP).dispatch();
          };};
    timer.schedule(task, interval, interval);
}

public void setInterval(long interval) {
    this.interval = interval;
    stop();
    start();
}

/**
 * 
 */
public void stop() {
    timer.cancel();
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
 */
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("GameTimer [timer=").append(timer).append("]");
    return builder.toString();
}
}
```

Comment: Its a own written class witch handles our timers. We will need to stop them, speed it up or slow it down. That works fine when called up somewhere else except when startet in the webserivce.

Comment: Have you imported that class in your web service?

Comment: Can you post StartGame class here

Comment: The webservice works fine, until i call this path^^

Comment: @Path("/{startGame}")

Comment: Try this and then tell

Comment: If i use GET annotation for sorting this problem won't that create any problem  for you no ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working here i have used a GET annotation which tells web service what to do.

```
@Path("/{startGame}")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)

public String startGame(){
    GameTimer timer = new GameTimer(1000);
    timer.start();
    return "Timer Started";
}
```

Hope it helps !